# Tzdata(tzdata.inc) Bug in Yocto fido

Tags: yocto, build-system

```
https://github.com/open-switch/ops-build/blob/master/yocto/poky/meta/recipes-extended/tzdata/tzdata.inc
```

Above is the link for `yocto-fido/poky/recipes-extended/tzdata`. when I compile above recipe it is not giving required out-put in `/usr/share/zoneinfo` in `rootfs`.

Is an error in the tzdata.inc? file please help.

Comment: Well, could you tell us what output you're expecting, that's not being produced?

Comment: @Anders After compiling the tzdata in my rootfs /usr/share/zoneinfo/Asia/culcutta file i need but it is not comming to my rfs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have update the tzdata.inc in my github source below is the link.

```
https://github.com/vsivanagulu/ops-build/blob/master/yocto/poky/meta/recipes-extended/tzdata/tzdata.inc
```